# how to solve the kwidget not defined in kaltura

Tags: kaltura

I have modified my modified my html5 library to point my kaltura server. Now I am able to play videos as static html webpage. but I tried in my project which is developed using php, it doesn't play the videos in even PC's too.

It says kwidget is not defined.

I used the kWidget embed code. But it s not happened in auto embed or flash embed.

But I read that kwidget is good to reduce the page load timings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using any MVC, you need to add the mwEmbedLoader script in the service or controller's head. I think you used the kwidget code in view sector and not add your script in controller page. you need to add your script in all the pages wherever the player function calls as below.

You can add that in couple of ways.

```
<script src="http://youkalturaserver.example.com/p/partnerId/sp/partnerId+00/embedIframeJs/uiconf_id/11170264/partner_id/partnerId"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://youkalturaserver.example.com/html5/html5lib/v2.69.7/mwEmbedLoader.php"></script>
```

replace v2.6.7 with current release version:
https://github.com/kaltura/mwEmbed/releases

It will solve this error